# Css style problems on input in IE8

Tags: html, css, input, textinput

I have a problem getting the text in an input to show correct in Internet Explorer 8.
Firefox, Safari and Chrome all show the same.

Firefox, Safari and Chrome

[image: Firefox, Safari and Chrome]

Internet Explorer 8

[image: Internet Explorer 8]

```
    <form action="" method="get">
       <input id="q" name="q" type="text">
       <input id="s" name="s" type="submit" value="Sök">
    </form>

#q {
    background:url(../../image_layout/search_field.png) no-repeat;
    width:209px;
    height:32px;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#09305b;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 19px;
}
#s {
    background:url(../../image_layout/serach_buttom.png) no-repeat;
    width:56px;
    height:34px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:0;
    position:absolute;
    left: 225px;
    top: 17px;
}
```

Comment: IE... Such a depressing piece of software :-( I feel your pain! One thing to try (if you haven't got it already) is to set the doctype to strict - I spent about 2 days making a site work in IE, and later realizing I'd accidentally used the Transitional doctype :-P Oh the pain.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try specifying a `line-height: 34px` or thereabouts.

Comment: Ah, the good old line-height how could I forget :) Funny that it doesn't seem to affect Firefox at all, where it already looks good. But it does the work for IE.

Comment: I tried this and it worked with placing the text correctly. However, in other, modern browsers the caret are now as tall as the input field, and it looks unnice.. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: @squ did you ever get a solution to the huge caret?  I have the same issue

Comment: @tmsimont Not really, I had to do an IE specific hack and set line height for only IE and do the regular height for the other browsers..

Comment: Worth having a look at answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14876642/731782 solved it for me.

Answer (score 11):

There is a *CSS3* rule: the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing). This rule is supported by IE8.

The IEs(including IE8) have non-standard box model, where `padding` and `border` are included into `width` and `height` whereas other browsers go with standard and don't include padding and border into width . It is described in detail [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).
By setting the `box-sizing` to `content-box` you tell the browsers not to include border and padding into width, and if you set `box-sizing: border-box`, all browsers will include border and padding into width. This or this, the display will be consistent across all modern browsers(not that IE8 is so modern, but it supports this rule too :).

Comment: +1. This was really helpful for a left padding issue I was having.  Did not know IE8 supported box-sizing.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh IE8 ... you never know from where it hits you next ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had to set the line-height *and* `display: inline`. No idea why, but it worked for me.

Comment: I take it back, that did actually work for me! Thanks Bergie3000

Answer (score 2):

Set a line-height property for search input field #q?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a line-height targeting IE8 and below, like this:

```
line-height: 32px\9;
```

`line-height` value should be equal to input's height and `\9` will target IE8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

The position of input should be `position:absolute;` in order for `line-height:37px;` and `display:inline;` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had much trouble with that, and finally i resolved it:

for ex. you set

```
  INPUT {
   line-height: 44px
}
```

and...

```
  INPUT:focus {
    line-height: 45px
 }
```

this one...f... pixel makes the difference (focus shoud have +1px more than normal) and now you have your cursor in good position at IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
line-height: 34px!important;
height: 34px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, Matthew's answer worked for me, but in case people wanted an IE-only wrapper without searching anywhere else:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```